# No wifi adapter found ubuntu on PC!

Tags: networking, drivers, realtek-wireless

In terminal,**sudo lshw -C network** shows

```
frozenmafia@frozenmafia-H81M-S:~/r8169$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for frozenmafia: 
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 0c
       serial: 40:8d:5c:a5:eb:f9
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.048.00-NAPI latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:28 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7800000-f7800fff memory:ea100000-ea103fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@3:2
       logical name: usb0
       serial: 9a:aa:c9:9d:42:68
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.199 link=yes multicast=yes
frozenmafia@frozenmafia-H81M-S:~/r8169$
```

But still no wifi adapter found.I am using a pc(no laptop).And the wifi adapter name is Tenda w311m.Please help.!

Comment: The listing you provided may not be complete as it warns, as you didn't elevate privileges (ie. by use of `sudo`).  You also haven't provided OS & release details.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide  (the *Device Recognition and Operation* section is what will help most)

Comment: @guiverc when i type lusb.i get Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0bda:b711 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11n WLAN Adapter
.Do you know which driver to use for this chipset.

Comment: Hey can you try to run the command `sudo lshw -C network` in the terminal.

Comment: @Dhyansaj it is  already done